# Simple integration testing using Flutter

Tags: widget, integration-testing, testcase, flutter-test

I am testing a flutter application. I am to run an integration testing, just like Espresso and Selenium allow UI testing, based on my reading, I got to understand that testing Flutter UI will require setting up the integration model. In Selenium `findById` and Espresso, we can use , `R.id.unique_element_id`.

I have tried undertsanding the unique id to reference widgets in Flutter but do not understand. Any simple test for a form like this

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter your username'
              ),
            ),
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter your phone number'
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),

            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
```

Setup the test file like this

```
    import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
    import 'package:test/test.dart';

    void main() {
      FlutterDriver driver;

      setUpAll(() async {
        driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
      });

      tearDownAll(() async {
        if(driver != null){
          driver.close();
        }
      });


test('tap on the button, verify result', () async {
    final SerializableFinder username = find.byValueKey('usernametextfield');
    expect(username, isNotNull);
    //insert value into username

    final SerializableFinder phonenumber = find.byValueKey('phone');
    expect(phonenumber, isNotNull);
    //insert value into phonenumber
});
```

How do I create such a tetscase and run. the comments `//insert value into username` and `//insert value into phonenumber` are actual testcases I want to complete.

Comment: I don't understand from your description what do you really want to achieve in your form. Flutter driver tests are fully automated tests. They are executed on a real device with a command "flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart". More about Flutter driver and examples are here https://medium.com/flutter-community/testing-flutter-ui-with-flutter-driver-c1583681e337 and official docs here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction

Answer (score 4):

flutter_driver is dead now(Discontinued) you can use this [integration_test](https://pub.dev/packages/integration_test)
I create login flow example

1. First add a dependency in pubspec.yaml under dev

   ```
          dev_dependencies:
            flutter_test:
              sdk: flutter
            test: ^1.9.4
            integration_test: ^1.0.1
   ```
2. Your package should have a structure that looks like this:
   [image]
3. Add this in test/test_driver/integration_test.dart

   ```
                  import'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart';

                                  Future<void> main() => integrationDriver();
   ```

4.Add this in integration_test/foo_test.dart
example

```
                                    void main() {
                                      IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
                                      testWidgets("Sign in test example", (WidgetTester tester) async {
                                        final Finder signInEmailField = find.byKey(Key('signInEmailField'));
                                        final Finder signInPasswordField = find.byKey(Key('signInPasswordField'));
                                        final Finder signInSaveButton = find.byKey(Key('signInSaveButton'));
  
                                        await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
  
                                        await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  
                                        await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('signInEmailField')));
                                        await tester.enterText(signInEmailField, "paras@gmail.com");
  
                                        await tester.tap(signInPasswordField);
                                        await tester.enterText(signInPasswordField, "123456");
  
                                        await tester.tap(signInSaveButton);
                                        print("button tapped");
                                        await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 1));
                                        expect(
                                            find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) =>
                                                widget is AppBar &&
                                                widget.title is Text &&
                                                (widget.title as Text).data.startsWith("ToDoApp")),
                                            findsOneWidget);
  
                                        await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 1));
                                      });
                                    }
```

5. Add key like we set in flutter_driver

   ```
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        title: Text(
                          'ToDoApp',
                          key: Key("toDoKey"),
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
                      ),
   ```
6. Foo last run the command in your terminal
   flutter drive 
   --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart 
   --target=integration_test/foo_test.dart

Thanks.. happy Fluttering

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found an answer to your question, but I am posting a solution here. Hope it helps.

Basically, you need to define `key` property on the `TextFormField` widget, which will help you to identify that widget uniquely and then you can perform actions on it. 
Example:

```
new TextFormField(
              key: Key('userNameTextField'),
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter your username'
              ),
            ),
```

and then in your test file, you'll write this:

```
test('tap on the button, verify result', () async {
    final SerializableFinder username = find.byValueKey('userNameTextField');
    expect(username, isNotNull);
    await driver.waitFor(username);
    await driver.enterText('Test');

  // repeat above for `phoneNumber` widget.

    final SerializableFinder phonenumber = find.byValueKey('phone');
    expect(phonenumber, isNotNull);
    //insert value into phonenumber
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer saved me

Comment: flutter_driver has now been discontinued (see next answer)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a method to enter text.
Maybe this will be useful for someone.

```
  Future<void> enterText(SerializableFinder itemFinder, String text) async {
    final isTextFieldPresent = await isPresent(itemFinder);

    if (isTextFieldPresent) {
      await _driver.tap(itemFinder);
      await _driver.enterText(text);
      await _driver.waitFor(find.text(text));
    } else {
      expect(isTextFieldPresent, true, reason: 'Cannot find text field');
    }
  }
```

And here is isPresent method I use above

```
  Future<bool> isPresent(SerializableFinder itemFinder,
      {int delayInMilis = 1000}) async {
    final timeout = Duration(milliseconds: delayInMilis);
    try {
      await _driver.waitFor(itemFinder, timeout: timeout);
      return true;
    } catch (exception) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```